# Which of the following inequalities is correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $w = u+iv$ and, $z = x+iy$ be complex numbers such that $w^2 = z^2 + 1$
Then which of the following inequalities must always be true?

(a) $x ≤ u$

(b) $y^2 \leq v^2$

(c) $v^2 \leq  y^2$

From my point of view all option are correct , because all are satisfying cauchy reimann equation . But my teacher   gave zero mark   for this  question . I don't why my teacher  gave zero mark for this question.
If anbody help me i would be very thankful to him

Comment: $(a)$ is not true in general. Choose, for example, $w=-1,z=0$

Comment: $(b)$ is not true in general. Choose, for example , $w=0,z=i$

Comment: $(c)$ seems to hold always, but I have no proof yet.

Comment: thanks a lot  ..@ peter when u will get  proved  pliz say me in detail..

Comment: Sorry but how is Cauchy-Riemann even involved here? "But my teacher gave zero mark for this question" No wonder.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(u+iv)^2-(x+iy)^2=u^2-v^2-x^2+y^2+2(uv-xy)i=1$$

so we have $$u^2-v^2-x^2+y^2=1$$ and $$uv=xy$$

Suppose, $v^2>y^2$ implying $0>-v^2+y^2$ hecen $1=u^2-v^2-x^2+y^2<u^2-x^2$ This implies $u^2>x^2+1>x^2$. $v^2>y^2$ and $u^2>x^2$ imply $v^2u^2>x^2y^2$ which is a contradiction to $uv=xy$ (which implies $u^2v^2=x^2y^2$) Therefore we must have $v^2\le y^2$, so $(c)$ is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

We prove (3) is correct. From $w^2=z^2+1$ we get $$(u+iv)^2-(x+iy)^2=u^2-v^2-x^2+y^2+2(uv-xy)i=1$$

so we have $$u^2-v^2-x^2+y^2=1$$ and $$uv=xy.$$

If $v=0$, then $v^2 \le y^2$. Now we assume $v\ne 0$, then $u^2=\frac{x^2y^2}{v^2}$ and $u^2-v^2-x^2+y^2=1$ becomes 
    $$\frac{x^2y^2}{v^2}-v^2-x^2+y^2=1$$
which is $$(y^2-v^2)(1+\frac{x^2}{v^2}) = 1, $$ or $$y^2-v^2 = \frac{v^2}{v^2+x^2} > 0$$